# creating image tables with while loop in php and last entry echos to wrong location

Tags: php, html, css, while-loop, footer

I am using a while loop to echo images and titles to a webpage.

My problem is that the last image being echoed (whether it is image number 2 or 6) is placed below the footer when displayed on the page:  [Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdRvp.png)

For whatever reason the div "footer" is being added in the middle of the content div and I have no idea why. Why would it be moving into a div it doesn't belong in, and specifically right after the second to last item listing?

Thank you much in advance!
Loop:

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM photos");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i<$num) {
    $name = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Name');
    $price = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Price');
    $price = '$'.$price;
    $description = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Description');
    $location = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Location');
    $id = mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');
    $status = mysql_result($result, $i, 'Status');

    echo "<table class='item'>
            <tr class='name'>
                <td><h2>" . $name . "</h2><h4>" . $type = ($status == "SOLD" ? $status : $price) . "</h4></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr class='imagelocation'>  
                <td><img src='" . $location . "' class='image'></td>
                <td class='itemdescription'>" . $description . " " . $price . "</td>
            </tr>
            ";
            $i++;
    }
?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<h5>For additional information, please <a href="contact.html">contact me</a>. <br />&nbsp;<br   />Copyright &copy; </h5>
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
</body>
```

Outputted HTML:

```
<div class="item_list"> 
<table class="item">
            <tbody><tr class="name">
                <td><h2>Curtis</h2><h4>$8291.23</h4></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr class="imagelocation">  
                <td><img src="images/HDR1.jpg" class="image"></td>
                <td class="itemdescription">Lorem</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>**<div id="footer">

</div>**<table class="item">
            <tbody><tr class="name">
                <td><h2>Vienna wall clock</h2><h4>SOLD</h4></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr class="imagelocation">  
                <td><img src="images/image001.jpg" class="image"></td>
                <td class="itemdescription">      </td>
            </tr>
</tbody></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<table class='item'>
            <tr class='name'>
                <td><h2>" . $name . "</h2><h4>" . $type = ($status == "SOLD" ? $status : $price) . "</h4></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr class='imagelocation'>  
                <td><img src='" . $location . "' class='image'></td>
                <td class='itemdescription'>" . $description . " " . $price . "</td>
            </tr></table>
            ";
```